# Ionic 5 changing grid size and applying style not working with react?

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic5

I am actualy very confused about how to center an Ionic Grid. I have try to put it in a div and add these different styling properties `justify-content, text-align, align-items` none of the thems worked. Any Idea to how I can figure this out without changing the width of it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to apply the styles on the columns tags to have the desired effects. As follows an example:

```
  <IonGrid>
    <IonRow>
      <IonCol className="ion-align-self-start">Content on start</IonCol>
      <IonCol className="ion-align-self-center">Content centered</IonCol>
      <IonCol className="ion-align-self-end">Content at the end</IonCol>
    </IonRow>
  </IonGrid>
```

Comment: For some reason className doesn't apply any styling to my components.. Also I meant to center the entire grid. My grid is on the left side of my page and I wanted to center it.

Comment: I don't know why your project are with this behavior. But, to center the an entire Grid, you may try to put it in a div and apply a css center style to it.